# Modifying Excel Templates from GUI

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

### The Idea

In an attempt to speed up a tedious process, I would like to write an application to help out with creating and saving repetitive spreadsheets. The template is always the same, but 3 cells vary with information, and I'd like a streamlined and simple GUI format to stamp these out.

### It must:

- Open template
- Update 3 cells with user-inputted data
- Be able to "Save as" a new file in a static, designated location with the filename as a concatenation of 2 of the 3 cells
- Be usable without opening the excel sheet/only opening it to briefly update then saving and closing it

### Caveats:

- Other content/formatting in the spreadsheet must be kept the same, no line insertions, just cell modifications
- The spreadsheet is a protected sheet, will this cause problems?

My initial thought is that a Visual Basic GUI app would hook in well with Excel on this one - but is the whole idea even possible?

Comment: The whole idea is perfectly possible through VBA. A userform might be the way to start of here.

Comment: @JvdV would that not be prevented by the fact that it's a protected sheet?

Comment: You can temporarily un-protect a sheet while your code is running.

Comment: @JvdV Follow up question - a userform requires me to open the sheet, no? At that point just swapping the 3 cells would be about the same amount of time. And could a userform perform my desired save-as function?

Comment: You can have your worksheet protected, and for example, upon `Workbook_Open()` use something like `UserForm.Show` to get to the userform. On that userform have three textboxes for the three user-inputted data. Add a button with a macro that will unprotect the sheet, edit the three cells, saves the template as a new static excel file, protect the worksheet.